# Как в ComboBox добавлять элементы?

Tags: c#, winforms

У нас есть скромная форма. А там скромный ComboBox. И кодом надо задать элементы. То есть у меня есть текст который надо вставить в свойство Items. Также как в среде. Всё бы ничего, вот только Items только возвращает значения, а не принимает их. Поэтому спрашиваю - как это сделать?

Просьба не кидать идеи с привязкой данных. Ибо это занятие лишнюю память займёт, да и время жалко.

Comment: `comboBoxName.Items.Add(некоторое_значение)`

Comment: Пиши в ответы, надо же как-то людей благодрить)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство [ComboBox.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает коллекцию элементов содержащихся в `ComboBox`.

Для добавления одного элемента в список вы можете использовать метод [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(value);
```

тогда как для нескольких элементов нужно использовать метод [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Ну в общем-то в документации https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items(v=vs.110).aspx в самом низу пример кода приведён:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text)
```